# React native build error while archive flipper based error

Tags: react-native

while taking archive build we are facing below error.please help us to solve.

Showing All Errors Only
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FKUserDefaultsPlugin

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlipperClient
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlipperKitLayoutPlugin
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlipperKitNetworkPlugin

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlipperKitReactPlugin

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SKDescriptorMapper

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SKIOSNetworkAdapter

we hide below line but not success.

## :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,